# Deny all for a table to everyone except sa

Tags: t-sql, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

In MS-SQL Server 2008 R2, is there a way to set a table permission to "deny all" (select, insert, update, delete), to all roles and user id (including the future ones), except to sa?

In other words, can a table be made invisible except to sa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

- db_owner will see it
- schema owner can see it
- references in a stored procedure won't check permissions
- ...

If you want an invisible table, put into it's own database and set no permissions at all. No need to DENY, just do not GRANT or CREATE USER

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. OK, is there any way to make a column invisible then? Perhaps it's OK to db_owner to see it.

Comment: Column level permissions are tricky but the same applies: they are at the bottom of an hierarchy. On reflection, you could try a separate schema (CREATE SCHEMA) and grant no premissions. But db_owner will see it too